# how to include querystring in asp hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

im trying to send  a querystring in a asp.net hyperlink im not sure its possible or not? im looping through a collection and i want to include the id for every object in the collection. the error im getting is p does not exist in the current context.  Here's my code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="margin:100px;width:900px">

    <% foreach (var p in products)
       {
            %> <!-- loop through the list -->

  <ul style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:300px;list-style-type:none;border-style:solid">
    <li ">

        <p><%= p.ProductName %></p>
        <p>€<%= p.Price %></p>
        <img src="<%= p.MainProductImage %>" width="150";height="150";/>
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="details" runat="server" Text="Details" NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID={0}", p.ProductID);%>' />

    </li>
    </ul>
            <% 
         }
      %>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using simple anchor tag `<a>` instead of `HyperLink` control ?

Answer (score -1):

instead of `<asp:HyperLink>` use

```
<a href='<%=string.Format("ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID={0}", p.ProductID);%>' alt="Details" >Details</a>
```